# could not determine current runlevel - docker installation

Tags: docker, runlevel

Installing `docker-ce` as part of `Dockerfile`, with below command:

```
ARG DOCKER_VERSION=18.06.1~ce~3-0~debian


RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg-agent \
    software-properties-common && \
    curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID")/gpg > /tmp/dkey; apt-key add /tmp/dkey && \
    add-apt-repository \
       "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID") \
       $(lsb_release -cs) \
       stable" && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install docker-ce=${DOCKER_VERSION:-18.06.1~ce~3-0~debian}
```

---

gives below messages:

```
Setting up docker-ce (18.06.1~ce~3-0~debian) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker.service → /lib/systemd/system/docker.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/docker.socket → /lib/systemd/system/docker.socket.
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
```

---

Is `invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel` an issue to not determine the runlevel?

Answer (score -2):

You are trying to run `Docker in Docker`. That is very advanced hackish approach and you should read more about it, e.g. old blogpost https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/.

I guess you will want to install only docker client (not a daemon) in the image, which will connect to docker daemon of host OS.

Comment: I do not find instructions to install docker client only

Comment: This doesn't answer OPs question. The runlevel warning occurs for other packages.